# React-Select breaking the dropdown

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-select

I am using the documentation for https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/ 
It is causing the dropdown part of the select to overflow to the next column
[image] as shown in the picture

I would want it to have the same behavior as this dropdown
[image]

Has anyone experienced this issue and do you have an idea how to fix it? I cant provide the code unfortunately so asking more in general if anyone knows what could cause this? 
thanks

Comment: so what behavior you want the dropdown?(I mean also in the documentation it is the same behavior...)

Comment: I've edited the post with what behavior I want

Comment: It will be really good if you post your code(or at least example) here (put code fork and post link):https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-select-custom-tag-edit

Comment: I'm gonna try to create a snippet but due to this being parts of other code I can't provide it all.

Comment: Turns out this is a bug in Chrome that is known already. Might be ways around it but so far I havent found anything

Comment: Why did you delete the old question? I answered it for you and it works fine!